# Adapters for multiple recyclerview

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm using many recyclerview with different contents. I need to develop adapter for each list? Or there is another solution?

Comment: ideally every recyelerview have its own adapter .. you should explain your question a bit more

Comment: Is there a better way to prevent redundancy of code? I think of solution like implement strategy pattern

Comment: You should have an adapter for each logical set of data. You could create an abstract adapter that simplifies a few stuff, but that would be up to you and how you write your code.

If you wanna ask something more specific, I'd be glad to help you if I can.

Comment: As per @AdeelTurk comment every recyclerview have it's own adapter.
but at the and it's depends on your requirement. if your item cell have same design go with single adapter and design is different go with multiple adpter.

Comment: @Arbaz.in  in i think multiple design plus the data you wanted to show in your view .. i mean its not like its impossible to create a single adapter for each type of recyclerview its about neat and clean , maintainable , debuggable code

Comment: you can have multiple adapters for a list... and reuse the ones you share between recyclers

Comment: @AdeelTurk yeah we can do with single adapter i didn't say it not possible